# how to create session (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, session

How do you log the user in, create and store the user's session?

(It will timeout on its own aswell? do you need to store it in a database?)

Comment: What session? What login? Please give us somewhat more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NSUserDefaults. Set their values when session starts [for some events like login etc] and erase them when you want to end the session [for the events like logout or timeout].

Answer (score 0):

if you need to hard store login data (Username/password) you shouldn't use `NSUserDefaults`. Keychain was created to do this (`SFHFKeychainUnit`).